# Removing unicode BEL \u0007 special character from json string

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii, xmlserializer

I have a JSON response from 3rd party API, and I am trying to convert that into XML file using c# code.
Response field in text view:

"description":"\u0007\tPost-show meet & greet with photo\r\n\u0007\tPremium seat at the front of the auditorium\r\n\u0007\

But while converting this I am getting

> System.ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x07, is an invalid character.

I have tried

1. Regex : Regex.Replace(content, "[^\x00-\x7F]", String.Empty) and Regex(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
2. Encoding: Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content));
3. Ascii check to skip value > 255
4. breaking into array to replace with empty string or to check every  character with System.Xml.XmlConvert.IsXmlChar, but u0007 breaks into 5 different characters,

but no luck so far.

JSON OBJECT to reproduce :

```
{
    "ageRestrictionText": "Under 14s must be accompanied by an adult. We cannot issue refunds to under 14s who are not accompanied by an adult.",
    "artists": [],
    "canSellViaApi": true,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Sport",
            "childCategories": [
                {
                    "id": 190,
                    "name": "Other"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "currencyCode": "GBP",
    "dateOnSale": "2021-09-03T10:00:00",
    "dateOnSaleUtc": "2021-09-03T09:00:00Z",
    "doorsOpen": "2022-10-17T19:00:00",
    "doorsOpenUtc": "2022-10-17T18:00:00Z",
    "facilityFee": 0.50,
    "ianaTimeZoneName": "Europe/London",
    "id": "DF-2026997",
    "mainImageUrl": "https://c.ststat.net/content/entimg/tour/an-evening-with-michael-bisping-2029282017-300x300.jpg",
    "multiEventBasketAllowed": false,
    "name": "An Evening With Michael Bisping",
    "narratives": [
        {
            "content": "1.         Your ticket purchase constitutes a personal, revocable license and, at all times, remains the property of the promoters. This ticket must be surrendered to the promoters upon request.<br />2.         Your ticket/s are sold by the promoters directly to you the consumer. Any tickets purchased by business or traders in breach of the terms and conditions of ticket sale will be cancelled. By accepting these terms and conditions you confirm that you are a consumer. <br />3.         Your ticket/s will immediately become invalid if resold, or offered for resale, unless the sale is through the official re-sale channels as advertised, or ticket agent fan-to-fan exchange (where applicable). Tickets sold via third parties and other unauthorised outlets, including online auction sites, are not valid for admission. The resale of a ticket renders it invalid and may lead to refusal of entry.<br />4.         Ticket sales are limited to a maximum of 6 per person/transaction.",
            "culture": "en-GB",
            "type": "Tour"
        }
    ],
    "onSale": true,
    "priceGroups": [
        {
            "description": null,
            "id": "PG_DF-2026997_1",
            "name": "Standard Pricing",
            "prices": [
                {
                    "availableQuantities": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4
                    ],
                    "bookingFee": 11.50,
                    "canSellViaApi": true,
                    "description": "\tPost-show meet & greet with photo\r\n\tPremium seat at the front of the auditorium\r\n\tExclusive item of merchandise\r\n\tShow ticket",
                    "faceValue": 110.00,
                    "id": "DF-2026997_1",
                    "ticketPrice": 121.50
                },
                {
                    "availableQuantities": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6
                    ],
                    "bookingFee": 9.60,
                    "canSellViaApi": true,
                    "description": "\tPremium seat in the front section of the auditorium\r\n\tExclusive item of merchandise\r\n\tShow ticket",
                    "faceValue": 70.00,
                    "id": "DF-2026997_2",
                    "includedPrices": [],
                    "isSeated": true,
                    "maxSell": 6,
                    "minSell": 1,
                    "name": "VIP HOT TICKET",
                    "onSale": true,
                    "parentPriceId": null,
                    "priceRestrictions": [],
                    "quantityMultiple": 1,
                    "salesChannel": "Web",
                    "statusText": "ORDER",
                    "ticketPrice": 79.60
                },
                {
                    "availableQuantities": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6
                    ],
                    "bookingFee": 5.75,
                    "canSellViaApi": true,
                    "description": null,
                    "faceValue": 35.00,
                    "id": "DF-2026997_3",
                    "includedPrices": [],
                    "isSeated": true,
                    "maxSell": 6,
                    "minSell": 1,
                    "name": "SEATS",
                    "onSale": true,
                    "parentPriceId": null,
                    "priceRestrictions": [],
                    "quantityMultiple": 1,
                    "salesChannel": "Web",
                    "statusText": "ORDER",
                    "ticketPrice": 40.75
                },
                {
                    "availableQuantities": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6
                    ],
                    "bookingFee": 3.75,
                    "canSellViaApi": true,
                    "description": null,
                    "faceValue": 25.00,
                    "id": "DF-2026997_4",
                    "includedPrices": [],
                    "isSeated": true,
                    "maxSell": 6,
                    "minSell": 1,
                    "name": "SEATS",
                    "onSale": true,
                    "parentPriceId": null,
                    "priceRestrictions": [],
                    "quantityMultiple": 1,
                    "salesChannel": "Web",
                    "statusText": "ORDER",
                    "ticketPrice": 28.75
                }
            ],
            "salePlatform": "Online"
        }
    ],
    "restorationLevy": 0.0,
    "seatingPlan": {
        "description": "Tyne Theatre & Opera House - Newcastle",
        "hasSeatSelectorLayout": true,
        "id": 1501,
        "imageUrl": "https://c.ststat.net/content/seatingplans/4fedc64d-747d-484b-b8bd-178120deb36a.jpg",
        "_links": [
            {
                "href": "https://ticketing-api.seetickets.com/v1/events/df-2026997/seatingplan",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "self"
            }
        ]
    },
    "starts": "2022-10-17T20:00:00",
    "startsUtc": "2022-10-17T19:00:00Z",
    "statusText": "Order",
    "textDate": null,
    "timeZoneAbbreviation": "BST",
    "tour": {
        "id": "DF-446241",
        "name": "An Evening With Michael Bisping",
        "_links": [
            {
                "href": "https://www.seetickets.com/tour/an-evening-with-michael-bisping",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "self:web"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://ticketing-api.seetickets.com/v1/tours/df-446241",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "self"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": [
        {
            "href": "https://ticketing-api.seetickets.com/v1/events/df-2026997",
            "method": "GET",
            "rel": "self"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://www.seetickets.com/event/an-evening-with-michael-bisping/tyne-theatre-opera-house/2026997",
            "method": "GET",
            "rel": "self:web"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: 1) How are you converting from JSON to XML?  the \u0007 might be simpler to remove on the JSON end.  2) Be careful not to confuse escaping in c# string literals with (which gets evaluated at compile time) with JSON escaping inside a string value (which occurs during runtime.)  I'm not sure you are doing that; a [mcve] would clarify.

Comment: The response string isn't valid JSON.  Give a [mcve].

Comment: Can't reproduce with the JSON shown in your edited question, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/6qOUnw.  Parsing the JSON in your question with `var root = JToken.Parse(json);` them converting to XML via `var xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "some_root_element_name");` works successfully.  Please provide a [mcve], if the problem can't be reproduced your question may get closed.